# Socket.io polling 404 in Laravel

Tags: node.js, sockets, laravel, express, socket.io

I am trying to implement a chat app with Socket.io
in to my Laravel app. The chat app works fine on it's own,
but I am having problems to make it work in Laravel.

I try to serve Laravel on port 8000 and the chat server on 8000.
I use Express 4.8.0 and Socket.io 1.0.6, Node 0.10.29 and nodemon for testing.

//server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http    = require("http").Server(app);
var io      = require("socket.io")(http);

http.listen(8000, function () {
 console.log('listening on *:8000');
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get("/*", function (req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.php");
});
```

//client.js:

```
var socket            = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

//html - dependencies, I tried all these:

```
<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
{{ HTML::script('/socket.io/socket.io.js') }}
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>
<script src="{{asset('/socket.io/socket.io.js')}}"></script>
```

and then for the client side (own code)

```
{{ HTML::script('js/client.js') }}
```

The CDN version of Socket.io gives constantly these kinds of logs:

```
"GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407425555977-15 404 (Not Found)".
```

The others ones just gives a js file not found log:

```
"GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)"
```

//folder structure:

> /public
>
> > /js
> >
> > > client.js
> >
> > /node_modules
> >
> > server.js

Can anyone see what I can do to make it work?

**EDIT**
//server.js

```
var socket  = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');

var app     = express();
var server  = http.createServer(app);

var io      = socket.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log("Connected server");
}

server.listen(8000);
```

//client.js

```
var socket;
$(document).ready(function () {
 socket            = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
});
```

//When I typ the global "socket" object in the log it says:

```
connected: false
disconnected: true
```

Comment: You can't serve two applications on the same port.

Comment: I now changed the port number for Socket.io and it now says: "Connected client". With the code of Blubberguy22. So I guess I am ready to go now :) Thanks ^^

Comment: Yay. It's probably because 8000 is a somewhat common port and it was being overtaken by some other application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have set it up incorrectly. I had the same exact problem you did (same errors and basic code layout). You need to do `npm install socket.io --save` while in the base directory of your page (the same as where your index.php file is located). Then you have to do the same for express (`npm install express --save`). You also have to change your server code. Change the creation of io from:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http    = require("http").Server(app);
var io      = require("socket.io")(http);
```

To:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Then remove the `app.use` and `app.get` as they are no longer needed for how this is going to be done. Then add `server.listen(8000);` at the end of the server.js. For dependencies, use: `<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>`. Then, to run your server, go to it in terminal and type `node server.js`. Then just connect to it with your client. Also, for events, in the server, use:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('someEvent', function(someVariables){
        //Do something with someVariables when the client emits 'someEvent'
        io.emit('anEventToClients', someData);
    });
    client.on('anotherEvent', function(someMoreVariables){
        //Do more things with someMoreVariables when the client emits 'anotherEvent'
        io.emit('anotherEventToClients', someMoreData);
    });
});
```

And in your client code:

```
socket.emit('someEvent', variables);
socket.on('anEventToClients', function(something){
    //Code when anEventToClient is emitted from the server
});
```

Comment: I changed my code of what you sayd (and using the CDN version), it still gives me the polling transport 404 issue.

Comment: Could you post your new code under your old code please?

Comment: If socket.io is trying to make ajax requests to that URL then the web socket connection has probablt not been opened correctly. Check the server code as @Blubberguy22 mentions above.