# Socket.io and PHP

Tags: php, html, events, socket.io, push

Can someone please tell me if socket.io is only useful if the page your clients will use is a HTML page.

I want to create a node server that can push events to my existing PHP pages.

The pages are different and not suffixed with html.

All the examples I read use Chatroom examples with Index.html etc.

I simply want to know if what I want to do is even feasible.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a php page the output is html. I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

PHP and socket.io work together. The only difference between doing it with html and with PHP is the way you link the two together (the common tutorial shows a way that only works with html, but there is another way that works with both html and php).

Try something like this (from a similar answer of mine, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189436/3842050):

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Then remove the `app.use` and `app.get` as they are no longer needed for how this is going to be done. Then add `server.listen(8000);` at the end of the server.js. For dependencies, use: `<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>`. Then, to run your server, go to it in terminal and type `node server.js`. Then just connect to it with your client. Also, for events, in the server, use:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('someEvent', function(someVariables){
        //Do something with someVariables when the client emits 'someEvent'
        io.emit('anEventToClients', someData);
    });
    client.on('anotherEvent', function(someMoreVariables){
        //Do more things with someMoreVariables when the client emits 'anotherEvent'
        io.emit('anotherEventToClients', someMoreData);
    });
});
```

And in your client code:

```
socket.emit('someEvent', variables);
socket.on('anEventToClients', function(something){
    //Code when anEventToClient is emitted from the server
});
```